# Desaparicion de datos array devuelto con ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hola buenas tengo un vector con objetos (clases PHP)cuando lo voy a devolver por ajax este me aparece vacio , llamo a la clase en la vista principal y cuando los voy a insertar tambien , el caso es que si veo el vector antes de devolverlo esta correcto , pero en el alert del servidor no me reconoce el contenido. Aintroducir la descripción de la imagen aquílguna idea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola RB58. Por favor, cambia las imagenes por el texto. Para formatear codigo , seleccionalo y pulsa `ctrl + k`. Para mejorar la calidad de la pregunta, lee [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo

Comment: Quizá sea cuestión de arreglar los caracteres extraños. JSON no es muy amigo de estos. ¿Puede que tengas un problema de codificación de texto?

Comment: Tienes problemas con la codificación. Para resolver ese problema de raíz, sin tener que aplicar soluciones a medio camino, [sugiero que consultes esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59510/29967).

Comment: Era la codificacion muchas gracias por las respuestas